# How to create a sign up page in vuetify, without having to create a whole new project?

Tags: javascript, vuetify.js

I dont know if this question makes any sense but when I am create an app with vuetify and I am about to create a sign up and sign in page for this app. Do I create a new project and create those pages? or is there some way I can create that sign in and sign up page in the same project as the main page?

Also, are there any resources anyone can lead me to that would explain how to integrate a sign up page into my existing project if I were to create two seperate vuetify projects to get this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perfectly develop the login and sign up in the same project. The best way to do this is by making a new git branch. Otherwise I wouldn't recommend it. You would do so when your login changes the way your app functions.

Otherwise I would develop it in a separate project.

Comment: Yes this might be the best way but are there any resources you can lead me to that shows how to integrate the sign up page project and the app project into one?